# Accessing chrome.devtools.network information from javascript

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I haven't yet found a straightforward answer to this question on the web yet, so I'll ask it again.

1. Is it possible to add the Chrome DevTools API to my webpage in javascript? I need to access this information programatically to do some automated usage logging of request size / timing.
2. If not, is there any other way (perhaps via an extension?) that this might be possible? Again, I need to access this information programatically.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing?hl=en) all the network timing is retrieved through the [Resource Timing API](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/). So just use that on your web page instead of trying to go through the DevTools API.

Using the DevTools API in your web page is not possible. It is only available to Chrome Extensions.

Comment: I should have specified that I'm asking more-so about request transfer size, not the time it took. I have multiple ways to get the time.

Comment: That's not possible to get using JS for any given resource. You need to look at the requests as they happen and grab the `content-size` from the header. Which unless they are ajax requests it isn't possible to get that kind of control.